# "Authentication Error" Response Using Salesforce .NET Toolkit Error

Tags: rest-api, api, .net, sdk

I have been looking into getting information, such as Contacts from a Developer Salesforce account I have created. I downloaded the Sample  .NET Console application from the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET Github](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) repository. However, I am getting an "Authentication Error" response when trying to authenticate using the OAuth key and secret ID's.

I haven't modfied the code from the Github sample in any way, so I am at a loss to why this error is being returned.

From reading multiple posts online, this is what I have done to try and fix the issue:

- Created a new Connected App that has:

  - All users may self-authorize
  - Relax IP Restrictions
  - Application permission set to "Full Access".
  - Generated Consumer Key and Secret.
- Generated a Security Token from my logged in account (that has full System Admin access)
- Ensure the user role has API Enabled.

I am at a loss to what else I need to do in order to get API access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're probably hitting an issue with TLS 1.0 not being available, and it being the default for many versions of .NET. see https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/issues/208

Comment: @superfell You have just saved me so many hours of investigation. It was driving me crazy. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS 1.1 or 1.2 is required to access salesforce [always for sandbox, for prod depends on if the critical update is turned on]. Unfortunately the default TLS version for many versions of .NET is 1.0, which causes problems. See [this issue](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/issues/208) in the toolkit project about TLS versions